# Чтение бинарного файла который содержит обьекты класса до конца

Tags: c++, fstream, binary-file

Есть класс info , у него есть методы read и write , как считывать данные с файла используя эти методы до конца в фукции main?

```
class info{
public:
    string PIB;
    int dd;
    int mm;
    int yy;
    char gender;
    void print() {
            cout << "ПІБ - " << PIB << endl;
            cout << "Число народження - " << dd << endl;
            cout << "Місяць народження - " << mm << endl;
            cout << "Рік народження - " << yy << endl;
            cout << "Пол - " << gender << endl;
    }
    void enter() {
        cin >> PIB >> dd >> mm >> yy >> gender;
    }
    void write(ostream& os)
    {
        os.write((char*)&dd, sizeof(dd));
        os.write((char*)&mm, sizeof(mm));
        os.write((char*)&yy, sizeof(yy));
        os.write((char*)&gender, sizeof(gender));
        size_t len = PIB.length() + 1;     
        os.write((char*)&len, sizeof(len)); 
        os.write((char*)PIB.c_str(), len); 
    }

    void read(istream& in)
    {
        in.read((char*)&dd, sizeof(dd)); 
        in.read((char*)&mm, sizeof(mm));
        in.read((char*)&yy, sizeof(yy));
        in.read((char*)&gender, sizeof(gender));
        size_t len;                         
        in.read((char*)&len, sizeof(len));
        char* buf = new char[len];         
        in.read(buf, len);                  
        PIB = buf;                         
        delete[]buf;                        
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Замените `void read(istream& in)` на

```
istream& read(istream& in)
```

и в помледней строке функции напишите

```
return in;
```

Тогда чтение до конца будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
for(info i; i.read();) {
    // Делаем с i что надо
    }
```